# Table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, landscape, xtab

I would to make the `table` in landscape mode. To do that, I used `pdflscape` package. But I couldn't get the desired result. How to do that?

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand\Lenv{\textsf}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\topcaption{The principal xtab package commands} \label{tab:xtab}
\tablefirsthead{\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tablehead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tablelasthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
concluded from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tabletail{\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline \hline}
\begin{center}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
\verb|\begin{xtabular}{...}| & This is equivalent to the normal
\verb|\begin{tabular}{...}| environment.
You supply the specification of the columns
just as for the normal \Lenv{tabular} environment.
\\
&
All commands that can be used within a \Lenv{tabular}
environment can also be used within
the \Lenv{xtabular} environment.
\\
&
Unlike the \Lenv{tabular} environment which prevents page breaking
within the tabular, the \Lenv{xtabular} allows page breaking, so that
tabulars can extend automatically across several pages.
... ... ...\\
\verb|\tablelasttail{...}| & The contents of this command are inserted before
the final (internal) \verb|\end{tabular}| of the table.
\\
&
For example, you might want to note that this is where
the table ends.
\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can load package `showframe`. The page is just not big enough.

Comment: Have a look at package `booktabs`. There you can find precious tips on »How to make tabular material more pleasing to the eye«. You can see, that vertical bars are discouraged.

Comment: Please indicate what the desired look might be.

Comment: Your image shows the table has been rotated, so if that is not the "desired result" you need to say what you _do_ want.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 \begin{xtabular}{|l|p{0.5\linewidth}|}
```

`lscape` does not change `\textwidth` in the landscape environment.

Comment: It is already there in my MWE. I want to make the table in landscape as the paper

Comment: @subhamsoni no your MWE uses `\textwidth`

Comment: @subhamsoni the table in your MWE is already rotated into landscape orientation, it was just no wider than in portrat

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `\textheight`. Since with landscape, text height and text width are not swapped, the width of the table is along the text height. Put proper value in `0.9\textheight`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand\Lenv{\textsf}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\topcaption{The principal xtab package commands} \label{tab:xtab}
\tablefirsthead{\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tablehead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tablelasthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
concluded from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Command}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Effect}} \\ \hline }
\tabletail{\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline \hline}
\begin{center}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|p{0.9\textheight}|}
\verb|\begin{xtabular}{...}| & This is equivalent to the normal
\verb|\begin{tabular}{...}| environment.
You supply the specification of the columns
just as for the normal \Lenv{tabular} environment.
\\
&
All commands that can be used within a \Lenv{tabular}
environment can also be used within
the \Lenv{xtabular} environment.
\\
&
Unlike the \Lenv{tabular} environment which prevents page breaking
within the tabular, the \Lenv{xtabular} allows page breaking, so that
tabulars can extend automatically across several pages.
... ... ...\\
\verb|\tablelasttail{...}| & The contents of this command are inserted before
the final (internal) \verb|\end{tabular}| of the table.
\\
&
For example, you might want to note that this is where
the table ends.
\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Had a thought just now. The `1` must me facing my side then it would be correct.

Comment: @subhamsoni What is `my side`?

Comment: @subhamsoni Confused. Now where does it face? Just to relate...